# Unable to add any controls from toolbox in Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Hi i have created new Windows Form application. Now in Form1 i want to add controls but in toolbox all controls are read only mode and i can't add it on form. You can see it in below image.

[image]

I cannot find what is wrong in it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can right click the toolbox and reset it. Not sure if it will help, but you could give it a shot...

Comment: Is your form not possibly "locked" ?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder No my form is not locked

Answer (score -1):

See this from Edwer Fang from the MSDN: Hello,

Do you mean you are not able to see toolbox or items in toolbox? What is the version of your VS2010?

You can take the following steps to see if they help:

a) Try to run devenv /ResetSettings (in command prompt), devenv /setup, and devenv /resetskippkgs, devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates to eliminate the related potential problem.

b) Try disabling Add-ins (e.g. “Tools” | “Add-in Manager”) or run “devenv.exe /SafeMode”.This can eliminate the possibility that third party Add-ins or packages are causing problems. (For more detailed VS command line switches information, see: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx )

c) Try creating a new project. Sometimes corrupted project settings can cause problems. These are project specific.

d) Try to reboot the operating system to safe mode. This can help to isolate whether any other applications are interfering with Visual Studio. Note that some features (like IIS) are not available under safe mode. Please check whether this can be applied or not. In addition to safe mode, we can also try “clean boot”: How to configure Windows XP to start in a "clean boot" state http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310353 .

e) Try to create a new user account. This can help isolate user profile corruption related causes.

If they all not help, I suggest you repair your Visual Studio to have it worked.

Please remember to mark the replies as answers if they help and unmark them if they provide no help

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vstsstart/thread/2b924ed5-e49c-4ca7-acb0-a3b18ce0d0bc